# Rails nested joins with a has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I have a DB that stores students answers to quiz questions. These are linked to Student Learning Outcomes that I want to review through a series of relationships described below. I am trying to do a count for how many questions were answered correctly and how many questions were answered incorrectly for each student learning outcome, but I keep receiving errors.  Thank you in advance for any help you provide.

The general mapping is

“Answer” answers a question that tests a “KnowledgeTopic” that covers many (“KtCoveredBySLO”) “StudentLearningOutcome”

My **models** have the following relationships:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :KnowledgeTopic
end

class KnowledgeTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :kt_covered_by_slos 
  has_many :student_learning_outcomes, through: :kt_covered_by_slos
end

class KtCoveredBySlo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :StudentLearningOutcome
  belongs_to :KnowledgeTopic
end

class StudentLearningOutcome < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kt_covered_by_slos 
  has_many :knowledge_topics, through: :kt_covered_by_slos
end
```

The query I am attempting to run is:

```
@answers = Answer.joins(:KnowledgeTopic => {:kt_covered_by_slos => :StudentLearningOutcome})

.select( 'student_learning_outcomes.id As student_learning_outcomes_id', 
                 :is_correct, "count(answers.id) AS total_answers")

 .group('student_learning_outcomes.id', :is_correct)
```

The error I am receiving is:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
>   kt_covered_by_slos.knowledge_topic_id:     SELECT
>   student_learning_outcomes.id As student_learning_outcomes_id,
>   "answers"."is_correct",    count(answers.id) AS total_answers     FROM
>   "answers" INNER JOIN "knowledge_topics"     ON "knowledge_topics"."id"
>   = "answers"."KnowledgeTopic_id" INNER JOIN "kt_covered_by_slos"     ON "kt_covered_by_slos"."knowledge_topic_id" = "knowledge_topics"."id"
>   INNER JOIN "student_learning_outcomes"     ON
>   "student_learning_outcomes"."id" =
>   "kt_covered_by_slos"."StudentLearningOutcome_id"     GROUP BY
>   student_learning_outcomes.id, is_correct

**Migrations:**

```
class CreateKtCoveredBySlos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :kt_covered_by_slos do |t|
      t.references :StudentLearningOutcome, index: true
      t.references :KnowledgeTopic, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.references :Question, index: true
      t.references :Section, index: true
      t.references :Student, index: true
      t.references :KnowledgeTopic, index: true
      t.boolean :is_correct
      t.string :answer_text
      t.references :Enroll, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateKnowledgeTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :knowledge_topics do |t|
      t.string :knowledge_area
      t.string :knowledge_unit
      t.string :knowledge_topic
      t.integer :year_added
      t.boolean :active
      t.integer :correct_answers
      t.integer :incorrect_answers
      t.integer :temp_correct_answer
      t.integer :temp_incorrect_answer
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateStudentLearningOutcomes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :student_learning_outcomes do |t|
      t.string :accredidation_body
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :year_added
      t.boolean :active
      t.integer :correct_answers
      t.integer :incorrect_answers
      t.integer :temp_correct_answer
      t.integer :temp_incorrect_answer
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you update your question with migrations for `Answer`, `KtCoveredBySlo`?  Your query shows two different column names for `KnowledgeTopic`'s foreign key.

Comment: Can you please also structure your queries the way it's easier to read, like splitting it on several lines.

Comment: Have you tried to follow rails convention and use snake_case naming in your migrations and association declarations in models or it's not an option?

Comment: ave- I thought I was based off the ruby guides at guides.rubyOnRails.org. snake case attributes and table names but when using a single entry in the table use camal case.  Is this incorrect?  Is there a place where I messed this up?

Comment: @KatieT, no, it is not correct. You only (should) use camel case for class and module names. I suggestion you to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong:  Your associations show KnowledgeTopic has a many-to-many with StudentLearningOutcome through the join table KitCoveredBySlo.    So, to query active record Answer.joins(:knowledge_topics) is the wrong query since Answers belongs to KnowledgeTopics.  What is the plain english query you want??

Comment: For each student learning outcome, I want to know how many questions Tom - were answered correctly and how many were answered incorrectly.  Each answer should be counted for each student learning outcome it tests (i.e. if an answer applies to 3 different student learning outcomes, it will be counted 3 times). Thanks.

Comment: Ave - I am unclear as to where I do not follow that convention?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: @KatieT, in your migrations look at the name of the arguments that you pass to `t.reference` and in your models looks at what arguments you pass to `belongs_to` method. According to convention they should be snake_cased and so should be arguments in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone.  Using Ave's explanation, I changed the reference names, and then updated everything else accordingly.  After that I was able to run the query with

```
@answers = Answer.joins(knowledge_topic: :student_learning_outcomes)
.select( 'student_learning_outcomes.id As student_learning_outcomes_id', :is_correct,   
    "count(answers.id) AS total_answers")
.group('student_learning_outcomes.id', :is_correct)
```